# in_array not giving correct result

Tags: php, arrays

I have been stuck with this for SO long, I thought I will ask advice here.

I have a variable called `$productName`: which when I print I get:

```
01_PRD_2001
```

Now I have an array named `$productList` that when printed gives me:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 01_PRD_2001

    [1] => 07_PRD_2002

    [2] => 11_PRD_2004

    [3] => 01_PRD_2003

)
```

But when I run:

```
if(in_array($productName,$productList))
{
    echo "This product is in stock";
}
else
{
    echo "This product is not in stock";
}
```

It always tells me `This product is not in stock`. This is driving me crazy now, what could be wrong?

Comment: Make sure to `trim()` the product name before comparing. You may have some extra white space there. How do you set `$productName`?

Comment: `I have been stuck with this for` **SO** `long` didn't knew that Stack Overflow is a new time unit! (Show us the **exact** output of `var_dump($productList);`)

Comment: @JayBlanchard I tried `in_array(trim($productName) ,trim($productList))` but it didnt work :(

Comment: `trim($productList)` won't have much effect because it's an array: `array_map('trim', $productList)` would be another matter

Comment: Seems to work [here](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/98bf-2xt1) just fine.

Comment: `trim($productList) === NULL` if `$productList` cannot be converted to a string. Bonus: a Warning is triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way to `trim` your array value using `array_map()` and then your single value using `trim()` function, finally check with `in_array()` .

```
$productList=array_map('trim',$productList); //trimmed array values
$productName=trim($productName);// trimmed single variable

if(in_array($productName,$productList))
{
    echo "This product is in stock";
}
else
{
    echo "This product is not in stock";
}
```